# Periodically check if a new version of my pwa is available

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I have a spa pwa which shows a nice "new version available, click here to update" message whenever a new version of my app is available (JS files, no app content per se). This works pretty well, it is implemented like described [in this article](https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/pwa-create-a-new-update-available-notification-using-service-workers-18be9168d717).

However, it only shows the update message if the user reloaded the page and already had the old service worker installed in their browser which makes sense given the `onupdatefound` hook is only executed when the service worker loads. I'm wondering, is there a way to periodically check if a new version of the app is available (with a `setTimeout` or something like that)? I'm not sure if that's currently even possible with today's browser api's.

Comment: You can use websockets for realtime communication or similar tools like socket.io. Also you can use hosted services like Firebase, which can update all devices about new update.

Comment: You can use periodic check with i.e. `cron` module as well, but you have to expect some extra traffic and it will take some time as I expect you dont want to call the endpoint each 5 seconds, but rather each 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @libik But the websocket/polling does not know if my pwa is updated. I've updated the question to precise I don't mean app content, but updated js files.

Comment: I am not expert for PWA apps, but in general you can always try to load one or more .js files in background with setting to `no-cache` with `cache-control` header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control and you can combine it with proper eTag functionality to not download same resources again https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag